# TYPO3 Form after Upgrade The property path should not be empty?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

after the Upgrade from Typo3 v10 to v11 i am getting the following error after trying to submit a form:

`The property path should not be empty.`

I checked the yamls but cant find any problems. I also checked the form finifshers.

Comment: Do you have multiple forms and does it happen on every form or only one of them? Did you try to add the form to an other page and check it there? Can you post the yaml of the malfunctioning form?

Comment: I only have this error with my own prototype. When i choose the standard prototype, there is no error.

Where can i upload the yaml?

Comment: Simply edit your question and copy & paste your code into it. Mark ist as code using the curly braces symbol or `<ctrl>` + `<K>`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with a form on `TYPO3 11`.
The reason was that a `<f:form.select>` had not a name or property attribute. Maybe it is in your case also a select tag or an `input` or `textarea` tag in your form that does not have one of these `attribute`s.

So please check if all your fields of that form have a name or property attribute and that its value is not an empty string and the error should not show up anymore.